# Understanding ECC in PERL

Tags: perl, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to understand elliptic curve cryptography by coding the algorithm in perl. But getting detailed information about implementing ECC is quite difficult.
So I gathered all informations together and started coding.

At first I searched for informations about a simple curve and I found it here: http://www.hjp.at/doc/rfc/rfc5639.html. Several curves from 160 upto 512 bits. Of course I started with the smallest one.

**EDIT:** Made a lot of mistakes, mostly due to the lack of information. But now this example works.

This is my perl script:

```
use bignum;
use Math::BigInt::Random;

my $p = hex "E95E4A5F737059DC60DFC7AD95B3D8139515620F";
my $a = hex "340E7BE2A280EB74E2BE61BADA745D97E8F7C300";
my $b = hex "1E589A8595423412134FAA2DBDEC95C8D8675E58";
my $x = hex "BED5AF16EA3F6A4F62938C4631EB5AF7BDBCDBC3";
my $y = hex "1667CB477A1A8EC338F94741669C976316DA6321";
my $q = hex "E95E4A5F737059DC60DF5991D45029409E60FC09";
my $bitLength = 160;

sub point_doubling {
    my ($px, $py) = @_;
    return $px, $py if $px == 0 && $py == 0;
    my $slope_numerator = 3 * $px * $px + $a;
    my $slope_denominator = 2 * $py;
    my $slope_denominator_inverse_modulo = $slope_denominator->bmodinv($p);
    my $slope_inverse_product = $slope_numerator * $slope_denominator_inverse_modulo;
    my $slope = $slope_inverse_product % $p;
    my $rx = (($slope * $slope - 2 * $px)) % $p;
    my $ry = (($slope * ($px - $rx) - $py)) % $p;
    return ($rx, $ry);
}

sub point_addition {
    my ($px, $py, $qx, $qy) = @_;
    return point_doubling($px, $py) if $px == $qx && $py == $qy;
    return $px, $py if $qx == 0 && $qy == 0;
    return $qx, $qy if $px == 0 && $py == 0;
    my $slope_numerator = $qy - $py;
    my $slope_denominator = $qx - $px;
    my $slope_denominator_inverse_modulo = $slope_denominator->bmodinv($p);
    my $slope_inverse_product = $slope_numerator * $slope_denominator_inverse_modulo;
    my $slope = $slope_inverse_product % $p;
    my $rx = (($slope * $slope - $px - $qx)) % $p;
    my $ry = (($slope * ($px - $rx) - $py)) % $p;
    return ($rx, $ry);
}

sub scalar_product {
    my ($k, $nx, $ny) = @_;
    my ($qx, $qy) = (0, 0);
    my $bit = 1;
    for my $bitCounter (1..$bitLength) {
        if ($k & $bit) {
            ($qx, $qy) = point_addition($nx, $ny, $qx, $qy);
        } 
        ($nx, $ny) = point_doubling($nx, $ny);
        $bit <<= 1;
    }
    return ($qx, $qy);
}

sub check_point_on_curve {
my ($qx, $qy) = @_;
return $qy * $qy % $p == ($qx * $qx * $qx + $a * $qx + $b) % $p ||
    $qy == 0 && $qx == 0;
}

print "Test if G is in curve:\n";
if (check_point_on_curve($x, $y)) {
    print "G is a point on the curve\n";
} else {
    die "ERROR: G is NOT a point on the curve\n";
}

# Creating the private key.
# 1.) A random integer dA with 0 < dA < q
my $dA = random_bigint(max => $q);

print "Private key chosen as $dA\n";

# 2.) Calculate the public key QA
my ($qax, $qay) = scalar_product($dA, $x, $y);

print "Public key calculated to ($qax, $qay)\n";

if (check_point_on_curve($qax, $qay)) {
    print "Public key is a point on the curve\n";
} else {
    die "ERROR: Public key is NOT a point on the curve\n";
}
```

The result looks likle this:

```
Test if G is in curve:
G is a point on the curve
Private key chosen as 14682691932678591389241030591930855095113892
Public key calculated to (1114548639616364108201749083649167655259366359581, 418437095262665064210367316915287142897094980157)
Public key is a point on the curve
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: When working mod p "division" is implemented by multiplying by the modular inverse. You can implement the extended euclidean algorithm in perl, or more simply just compute 1/a = a ** (p-2) mod p if p is a prime.

Comment: Thanks GregS, I corrected my listing accordingly.

Comment: good work, thanks for posting. I didn't realize `Math::Bigint` included a modular inverse method.